# Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <Error> (thread=Cluster, member=5): Full Thread Dump

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, dump, oracle-coherence

can someone help me with this problem?
I have one cluster node on a linux server.bellow is the tangosol-coherence-override.xml

```
    <cluster-config>
<member-identity>
<cluster-name system-property="tangosol.coherence.cluster">multicast_test</cluster-name>
</member-identity>
<multicast-listener>
<address system-property="tangosol.coherence.clusteraddress">224.3.6.15</address>
<port system-property="tangosol.coherence.clusterport">3059</port>
<time-to-live system-property="tangosol.coherence.ttl">3</time-to-live>
</multicast-listener>
</cluster-config>
<logging-config>
<severity-level system-property="tangosol.coherence.log.level">5</severity-level>
<character-limit system-property="tangosol.coherence.log.limit">0</character-limit>
</logging-config>
</coherence>
```

coherence-cache-config.xml :

```
<defaults>
   <serializer system-property="tangosol.coherence.serializer">java</serializer>
    <socket-provider system-property="tangosol.coherence.socketprovider"/>
  </defaults>

   <caching-scheme-mapping>
        <cache-mapping>
            <cache-name>dist-*</cache-name>
            <scheme-name>example-distributed</scheme-name>
        </cache-mapping>
    </caching-scheme-mapping>

    <caching-schemes>
      <distributed-scheme>
         <scheme-name>example-distributed</scheme-name>
         <service-name>DistributedCache</service-name>
         <lease-granularity>member</lease-granularity>
         <backing-map-scheme>
           <local-scheme/>
         </backing-map-scheme>
         <autostart>true</autostart>
      </distributed-scheme>
    </caching-schemes>
```

and then I have a client on a window pc to connect this cluster. on the client side ,all the config file is same as the cluster side.

code on client side is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     System.setProperty("tangosol.coherence.override", "path of tangosol.coherence.override.xml");
     System.setProperty("tangosol.coherence.cacheconfig", "path of coherence-cache-config.xml");
     NamedCache nc = CacheFactory.getCache("dist-a");
//a dead loop make this client node still running
        for (;;) {
            nc.get("name1");
            nc.put("name1", "");
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
}
```

when I start my simple client,on the cluster side I can see message like this:

```
2015-04-17 15:40:57.025/2855.491 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=1): Member(Id=4, Timestamp=2015-04-17 15:40:57.031, Address=192.168.1.67:8088, MachineId=32935, Location=site:,machine:MRCUIPENG-PC,process:8128, Role=TestCnGovCustomsCaspPureClient) joined Cluster with senior member 1
2015-04-17 15:40:57.272/2855.738 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=1): Member 4 joined Service Management with senior member 1
2015-04-17 15:40:57.530/2855.996 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=1): Member 4 joined Service DistributedCache with senior member 1
2015-04-17 15:40:57.577/2856.043 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=DistributedCache, member=1): 1> Transferring vulnerable PartitionSet{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127} to member 4 requesting 128
2015-04-17 15:40:57.631/2856.097 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D4> (thread=DistributedCache, member=1): 1> Transferring 129 out of 129 partitions to a machine-safe backup 1 at member 4 (under 129)
2015-04-17 15:40:57.640/2856.106 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=DistributedCache, member=1): Transferring 0KB of backup[1] for PartitionSet{128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256} to member 4
2015-04-17 15:41:02.565/2861.031 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <Warning> (thread=Cluster, member=1): Failed to reach address /192.168.1.67 within the IpMonitor timeout. Members [Member(Id=4, Timestamp=2015-04-17 15:40:57.031, Address=192.168.1.67:8088, MachineId=32935, Location=site:,machine:MRCUIPENG-PC,process:8128, Role=TestCnGovCustomsCaspPureClient)] are suspect.
2015-04-17 15:41:02.565/2861.031 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <Warning> (thread=Cluster, member=1): Timed-out members MemberSet(Size=1
  Member(Id=4, Timestamp=2015-04-17 15:40:57.031, Address=192.168.1.67:8088, MachineId=32935, Location=site:,machine:MRCUIPENG-PC,process:8128, Role=TestCnGovCustomsCaspPureClient)
  ) will be removed.
2015-04-17 15:41:02.565/2861.031 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=1): Member 4 left service Management with senior member 1
2015-04-17 15:41:02.565/2861.031 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=1): Member 4 left service DistributedCache with senior member 1
2015-04-17 15:41:02.565/2861.031 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=1): Member(Id=4, Timestamp=2015-04-17 15:41:02.565, Address=192.168.1.67:8088, MachineId=32935, Location=site:,machine:MRCUIPENG-PC,process:8128, Role=TestCnGovCustomsCaspPureClient) left Cluster with senior member 1
2015-04-17 15:41:02.573/2861.039 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <Info> (thread=DistributedCache, member=1): Restored from backup 128 partitions
2015-04-17 15:41:02.573/2861.039 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D4> (thread=DistributedCache, member=1): 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127,
```

on client side ,after few operations ,accour a Full Thread Dump exception:

```
2015-04-17 15:44:25.709/0.296 Oracle Coherence 3.7.1.0 <Info> (thread=main, member=n/a): Loaded operational configuration from "jar:file:/D:/workplace/CoherenceSDKTest/lib/coherence.jar!/tangosol-coherence.xml"
2015-04-17 15:44:25.725/0.312 Oracle Coherence 3.7.1.0 <Info> (thread=main, member=n/a): Loaded operational overrides from "file:/D:/workplace/CoherenceSDKTest/config/client/member/unsafe/tangosol-coherence-override.xml"
2015-04-17 15:44:25.725/0.312 Oracle Coherence 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=main, member=n/a): Optional configuration override "/custom-mbeans.xml" is not specified
2015-04-17 15:44:25.725/0.312 Oracle Coherence 3.7.1.0 <D6> (thread=main, member=n/a): Loaded edition data from "jar:file:/D:/workplace/CoherenceSDKTest/lib/coherence.jar!/coherence-grid.xml"

Oracle Coherence Version 3.7.1.0 Build 27797
 Grid Edition: Development mode
Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

2015-04-17 15:44:25.896/0.483 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <Info> (thread=main, member=n/a): Loaded cache configuration from "file:/D:/workplace/CoherenceSDKTest/config/client/member/unsafe/coherence-cache-config.xml"
2015-04-17 15:44:26.411/0.998 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D4> (thread=main, member=n/a): TCMP bound to /192.168.1.67:8088 using SystemSocketProvider
2015-04-17 15:44:26.553/1.140 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D7> (thread=PacketListenerN, member=n/a): Growing MultiplexingWriteBufferPool segment '65536' to 2 generations
2015-04-17 15:44:26.646/1.233 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D7> (thread=PacketListenerN, member=n/a): Growing MultiplexingWriteBufferPool segment '65536' to 3 generations
2015-04-17 15:44:26.646/1.233 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D7> (thread=PacketListener1, member=n/a): Growing MultiplexingWriteBufferPool segment '65536' to 4 generations
2015-04-17 15:44:27.676/2.263 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <Info> (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): This Member(Id=4, Timestamp=2015-04-17 15:40:57.031, Address=192.168.1.67:8088, MachineId=32935, Location=site:,machine:MRCUIPENG-PC,process:8128, Role=TestCnGovCustomsCaspPureClient, Edition=Grid Edition, Mode=Development, CpuCount=8, SocketCount=8) joined cluster "multicast_test" with senior Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2015-04-17 14:53:24.483, Address=192.168.1.124:8088, MachineId=44907, Location=site:,machine:app03,process:50455,member:node1, Role=CoherenceServer, Edition=Grid Edition, Mode=Development, CpuCount=2, SocketCount=2)
2015-04-17 15:44:27.676/2.263 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <Warning> (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): This member is configured with a multicast TTL of 4; the senior Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2015-04-17 14:53:24.483, Address=192.168.1.124:8088, MachineId=44907, Location=site:,machine:app03,process:50455,member:node1, Role=CoherenceServer) is configured with a TTL of 3. It is strongly recommended to use the same TTL setting for all cluster members.
2015-04-17 15:44:27.880/2.467 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D7> (thread=PacketListenerN, member=n/a): Growing MultiplexingWriteBufferPool segment '65536' to 5 generations
2015-04-17 15:44:27.880/2.467 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D7> (thread=PacketListener1, member=n/a): Growing MultiplexingWriteBufferPool segment '65536' to 6 generations
2015-04-17 15:44:27.880/2.467 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D6> (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): TcpRing connecting to Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2015-04-17 14:53:24.483, Address=192.168.1.124:8088, MachineId=44907, Location=site:,machine:app03,process:50455,member:node1, Role=CoherenceServer)
2015-04-17 15:44:27.880/2.467 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D6> (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): TcpRing connected to Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2015-04-17 14:53:24.483, Address=192.168.1.124:8088, MachineId=44907, Location=site:,machine:app03,process:50455,member:node1, Role=CoherenceServer)
2015-04-17 15:44:27.880/2.467 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): Member 1 joined Service Management with senior member 1
2015-04-17 15:44:27.880/2.467 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): Member 1 joined Service DistributedCache with senior member 1
2015-04-17 15:44:27.880/2.467 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): Member 1 joined Service ReplicatedCache with senior member 1
2015-04-17 15:44:27.880/2.467 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): Member 1 joined Service OptimisticCache with senior member 1
2015-04-17 15:44:27.880/2.467 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): Member 1 joined Service InvocationService with senior member 1
2015-04-17 15:44:27.880/2.467 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <Info> (thread=main, member=n/a): Started cluster Name=multicast_test

Group{Address=224.3.6.15, Port=3059, TTL=4}

MasterMemberSet(
  ThisMember=Member(Id=4, Timestamp=2015-04-17 15:40:57.031, Address=192.168.1.67:8088, MachineId=32935, Location=site:,machine:MRCUIPENG-PC,process:8128, Role=TestCnGovCustomsCaspPureClient)
  OldestMember=Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2015-04-17 14:53:24.483, Address=192.168.1.124:8088, MachineId=44907, Location=site:,machine:app03,process:50455,member:node1, Role=CoherenceServer)
  ActualMemberSet=MemberSet(Size=2
    Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2015-04-17 14:53:24.483, Address=192.168.1.124:8088, MachineId=44907, Location=site:,machine:app03,process:50455,member:node1, Role=CoherenceServer)
    Member(Id=4, Timestamp=2015-04-17 15:40:57.031, Address=192.168.1.67:8088, MachineId=32935, Location=site:,machine:MRCUIPENG-PC,process:8128, Role=TestCnGovCustomsCaspPureClient)
    )
  MemberId|ServiceVersion|ServiceJoined|MemberState
    1|3.7.1|2015-04-17 14:53:24.483|JOINED,
    4|3.7.1|2015-04-17 15:40:57.235|JOINED
  RecycleMillis=2400000
  RecycleSet=MemberSet(Size=0
    )
  )

TcpRing{Connections=[1]}
IpMonitor{AddressListSize=1}

2015-04-17 15:44:27.911/2.498 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Invocation:Management, member=4): Service Management joined the cluster with senior service member 1
2015-04-17 15:44:28.130/2.717 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=DistributedCache, member=4): Service DistributedCache joined the cluster with senior service member 1
2015-04-17 15:44:28.193/2.780 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D4> (thread=DistributedCache, member=4): Asking member 1 for 128 primary partitions
2015-04-17 15:44:33.357/7.944 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <Error> (thread=Cluster, member=4): Received cluster heartbeat from the senior Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2015-04-17 14:53:24.483, Address=192.168.1.124:8088, MachineId=44907, Location=site:,machine:app03,process:50455,member:node1, Role=CoherenceServer) that does not contain this Member(Id=4, Timestamp=2015-04-17 15:40:57.031, Address=192.168.1.67:8088, MachineId=32935, Location=site:,machine:MRCUIPENG-PC,process:8128, Role=TestCnGovCustomsCaspPureClient); stopping cluster service.
2015-04-17 15:44:33.357/7.944 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <Error> (thread=Cluster, member=4): Full Thread Dump

Thread[DistributedCache,5,Cluster]
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.onWait(Daemon.CDB:18)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.Service.onWait(Service.CDB:4)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.onWait(Grid.CDB:3)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:39)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Thread[Logger@9229206 3.7.1.0,3,main]
    com.tangosol.util.Base.replace(Base.java:2340)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.Logger.formatMessage(Logger.CDB:23)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.Logger.onNotify(Logger.CDB:57)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.application.console.Coherence$Logger.onNotify(Coherence.CDB:4)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:42)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Thread[PacketListenerN,8,Cluster]
    java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
    java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:136)
    java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:725)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.socket.UdpSocket.receive(UdpSocket.CDB:22)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.UdpPacket.receive(UdpPacket.CDB:1)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.packetProcessor.PacketListener.onNotify(PacketListener.CDB:20)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:42)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)

Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]

Thread[PacketListener1,8,Cluster]
    java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
    java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:136)
    java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:725)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.socket.UdpSocket.receive(UdpSocket.CDB:22)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.UdpPacket.receive(UdpPacket.CDB:1)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.packetProcessor.PacketListener.onNotify(PacketListener.CDB:20)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:42)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

Thread[IpMonitor,6,Cluster]
    java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.isReachable0(Native Method)
    java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.isReachable(Inet6AddressImpl.java:59)
    java.net.InetAddress.isReachable(InetAddress.java:420)
    java.net.InetAddress.isReachable(InetAddress.java:379)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.IpMonitor.onNotify(IpMonitor.CDB:12)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:42)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Thread[PacketSpeaker,8,Cluster]
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.queue.ConcurrentQueue.waitForEntry(ConcurrentQueue.CDB:16)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.queue.ConcurrentQueue.remove(ConcurrentQueue.CDB:7)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Queue.remove(Queue.CDB:1)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.packetProcessor.PacketSpeaker.onNotify(PacketSpeaker.CDB:21)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:42)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Thread[Cluster|Member(Id=4, Timestamp=2015-04-17 15:40:57.031, Address=192.168.1.67:8088, MachineId=32935, Location=site:,machine:MRCUIPENG-PC,process:8128, Role=TestCnGovCustomsCaspPureClient),5,Cluster]
    java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method)
    java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1530)
    com.tangosol.net.GuardSupport.logStackTraces(GuardSupport.java:810)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.ClusterService$SeniorMemberHeartbeat.onReceived(ClusterService.CDB:33)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.onMessage(Grid.CDB:34)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.onNotify(Grid.CDB:33)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.ClusterService.onNotify(ClusterService.CDB:3)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:42)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Thread[Attach Listener,5,system]

Thread[main,5,main]
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.poll(Grid.CDB:26)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.poll(Grid.CDB:11)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.get(PartitionedCache.CDB:26)
    com.tangosol.util.ConverterCollections$ConverterMap.get(ConverterCollections.java:1655)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$ViewMap.get(PartitionedCache.CDB:1)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeNamedCache.get(SafeNamedCache.CDB:1)
    test.cn.gov.customs.casp.sdk.hmdg.PureClient.main(PureClient.java:13)

Thread[PacketPublisher,6,Cluster]
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.onWait(Daemon.CDB:18)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.packetProcessor.PacketPublisher.onWait(PacketPublisher.CDB:2)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:39)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Thread[Invocation:Management:EventDispatcher,5,Cluster]
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.onWait(Daemon.CDB:18)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.Service$EventDispatcher.onWait(Service.CDB:7)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:39)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Thread[Invocation:Management,5,Cluster]
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.onWait(Daemon.CDB:18)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.Service.onWait(Service.CDB:4)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.onWait(Grid.CDB:3)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:39)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Thread[PacketReceiver,7,Cluster]
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.onWait(Daemon.CDB:18)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.packetProcessor.PacketReceiver.onWait(PacketReceiver.CDB:2)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:39)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Thread[PacketListener1P,8,Cluster]
    java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
    java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:136)
    java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:725)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.socket.UdpSocket.receive(UdpSocket.CDB:22)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.UdpPacket.receive(UdpPacket.CDB:1)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.packetProcessor.PacketListener.onNotify(PacketListener.CDB:20)
    com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:42)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

2015-04-17 15:44:33.357/7.944 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): Service Cluster left the cluster
2015-04-17 15:44:33.357/7.944 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=Invocation:Management, member=n/a): Service Management left the cluster
2015-04-17 15:44:33.357/7.944 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.0 <D5> (thread=DistributedCache, member=n/a): Service DistributedCache left the cluster
Exception in thread "main" com.tangosol.net.RequestPolicyException: Service has been terminated
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.onMissingStorage(PartitionedCache.CDB:32)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.ensureRequestTarget(PartitionedCache.CDB:29)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.get(PartitionedCache.CDB:18)
    at com.tangosol.util.ConverterCollections$ConverterMap.get(ConverterCollections.java:1655)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$ViewMap.get(PartitionedCache.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeNamedCache.get(SafeNamedCache.CDB:1)
    at test.cn.gov.customs.casp.sdk.hmdg.PureClient.main(PureClient.java:13)
```

for tow sides use port 8088 make connection，I collect some information about port 8088  .

at this point,exception does not come out

```
TCP    192.168.1.67:8088      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7056
 TCP    192.168.1.67:8088      192.168.1.124:50331    ESTABLISHED     7056
 TCP    192.168.1.67:50032     192.168.1.124:8088     TIME_WAIT       0
 TCP    192.168.1.67:50034     192.168.1.124:8088     ESTABLISHED     7056
 UDP    192.168.1.67:8088      *:*                                    7056
```

when exception come out:

```
TCP    192.168.1.67:50032     192.168.1.124:8088     TIME_WAIT       0
```

I do not know what this mean.

Comment: By the way ,I have try to   start a cluster node on my window pc ,and then use my client to connect . the exception disappears

Comment: I seem to remember that we had this problem on a linux machine, I'll try and dig out what the problem was, but I'm sure it was fixed by going through the items on the Coherence production check list. It was something to do with multicast traffic and a setting on the network adapter, I'll try and find out what we did and post here... (Nodes were able to join, but then they got kicked out after a minute or something)

Comment: I think it was the switch setup - I am not a network expert, but it was something to do with multicast set up and IGMP Snooping / IGMP Querier. Before the configuration of the switch was changed, we started out cluster and after 5 minutes, nodes would stop communicating

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, it sounds like this is a networking problem.

We had to change the configuration of our switch when this happened.

The switch had to be set up to allow http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGMP_snooping / IGMP_querier

(I'm not a network bod, so I am not sure exactly what was changed)

Try testing your network using the Coherence Multicast test Tool. If you can run it for over five minutes without any problems, then this should indicate that IGMP Query is working.

Comment: Hi bret.I run the multcast-test script on my pc and the linux server over 11 minutes.everything is ok!

Comment: if the problem is about IGMP, why the question focus on port 8088 not 3059 (in tangosol-coherence-override.xml)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using the API of coherence 12c

To visit a cluster build by coherence 3.7。just version conflict。